# expo is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: react-native, expo

I am having trouble getting expo start to work.
I completely uninstalled both expo and expo-cli with npm and yarn and then installed expo-cli globally with npm and I still get the same error. I think it has something to do with the most recent expo-cli update, because it was working perfectly fine. So how can I install an older version of expo-cli?

I also don't see any path in the environment variables? Could that have something to do it?

Comment: It was working on my other computer, but when I tried to update expo, expo installed, but expo-cli won't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the update messed with the path.
So I had to go to edit environment variables and add another line to the variable "Path" under the system variables.

Don't hit new. Click on "Path" under the system variables section and add a new line there. and use "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm".

Then open a new command line and it should work.